# Yarn can't use arguments on custom scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp, yarnpkg

I have a few projects that uses the same structure, so I have a bunch of scripts set on package.json to run each project for development and production.

I was able to create custom args on the script command and pass it to gulp and webpack. This part is working as expected.

The is that when I run this script below I get this error on the terminal: `Error: Unknown option '--theme'`.

> yarn dev -- --theme=clienta

This is my current package.json scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
  "new": "gulp new --theme=clienta",
  "d:clienta": "webpack --env --theme=clienta --config webpack/dev.js --watch",
  "b:clienta": "webpack --env --theme=clienta --config webpack/build.js && gulp build --theme clienta --type",
  "d:clientb": "webpack --env --theme=clientb --config webpack/dev.js --watch",
  "b:clientb": "webpack --env --theme=clientb --config webpack/build.js && gulp build --theme clientb --type",
  "d:clientc": "webpack --env --theme=clientc --config webpack/dev.js --watch",
  "b:clientc": "webpack --env --theme=clientc --config webpack/build.js && gulp build --theme clientc --type"
},
```

How can I run my yarn script in a way that I can pass the arguments to the script? Something like this:

> yarn dev -- --theme=clienta

```json
"scripts": {
  "new": "gulp new --theme",
  "dev": "webpack --env --theme --config webpack/dev.js --watch",
  "build": "webpack --env --theme --config webpack/build.js && gulp build --theme --type"
},
```

So instead of having to create dev and build scripts for each project, I can just pass the argument.